# Returning row number on MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have 4 tables, from which i select data with help of joins in select query...I want a serial no.(row number) per record as they are fetched. first fetched record should be 1, next 2 and so on...

In oracle the equiavelent in RowNum.

Comment: Have you considered implementing the rownumber outside your query? There are a number of possibilities that I might be able to offer if I kew exactly what you plan on using the rownumber for in your application. Add some details and I'll answer with the most appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Brettski is ASP flavored and would need a lot of editing.

```vb
SELECT DCOUNT("YourField","YourTable","YourField <= '" & [counter] & "'") 
  AS RowNumber,  
  YourField as counter FROM YourTable;
```

Above is your basic syntax.  You are likely to find this runs very slow.  My typical solution is a bucket table with Autonumber field.  That seems kludgy, but it gives me control and probably in this case it allows speed.

Comment: "bucket table with Autonumber field" is in line with what JohnFX said early on ...

Answer (score 0):

Using a sorted Make Table Query in Access, I use the following (wouldn't work if you look at the Query, as that would increment the number when you don't want it to)....

```
setRowNumber 'resetting increment before running SQL
DoCmd.RunSQL ... , rowNumber([Any Field]) AS ROW, ...

'Increment Number: Used to create temporary sorted Table for export
Private ROWNUM As Long

'dummyField: must take an input to update in Query
Public Function rowNumber(ByVal dummyField As Variant, Optional ByVal incBy As Integer = 1) As Long
    ROWNUM = ROWNUM + incBy 'increments before value is returned
    rowNumber = ROWNUM
End Function

Public Function setRowNumber(Optional ByVal setTo As Long = 0) As Long
    ROWNUM = setTo
    setRowNumber = ROWNUM
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

With the following table

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

CREATE TABLE people 
( 
    firstName VARCHAR(32), 
    lastName VARCHAR(32) 
) 
GO 

INSERT people VALUES('Aaron', 'Bertrand') 
INSERT people VALUES('Andy', 'Roddick') 
INSERT people VALUES('Steve', 'Yzerman') 
INSERT people VALUES('Steve', 'Vai') 
INSERT people VALUES('Joe', 'Schmoe')
```

You can use a sub query to create the counting row:

```
SELECT 
    rank = COUNT(*), 
    a.firstName, 
    a.lastName 
FROM 
    people a  
    INNER JOIN people b 
    ON  
        a.lastname > b.lastname 
        OR 
        ( 
            a.lastName = b.lastName 
            AND 
            a.firstName >= b.firstName 
        ) 
GROUP BY 
    a.firstName, 
    a.lastName 
ORDER BY 
    rank
```

The problem with this method is that the count will be off if there are duplicates in your results set.

This [article](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-return-row-numbers-with-my-query.html) explains pretty well how to add a row counting column to your query.

Comment: Does your script run in Access?

Comment: It seems to be MSSQL script, but not an MS Access query