# SQL Select statement between row number n and j

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

How can i select rows from 500 to 1000 using the select statement?

Comment: Access Database and i am using vb.net

Comment: @user1570048 does your table have a numeric ID field that would correspond to 500-1000?

Comment: What determines which row is row 500?  How are the data ordered?

Comment: When you say rows 500 to 1000, what's your criteria? Sql rows are not ordered by anything and thus their order could be different on different select statements. Unless you have a specific id or date-stamps this question makes no sense.

Comment: check this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701243/returning-row-number-on-ms-access, you can then do `select * from tbl where rownumber between 500 and 1000`

Comment: no it doesn't have numerical value if it did i wouldnt ask

Comment: its like when you say "Select TOP 500 * ..."

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Access LIMIT X, Y](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627032/ms-access-limit-x-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more info, I will suggest selecting the top 1000, then selecting the bottom 500 from that.

Edit: Record order is by field called name.  Perhaps something like:

```
select top 500 name
from 
(
select top 24000 name
from table
order by name
)
order by name desc
```

Please note: Name is a reserved word and a bad choice for a field name.

Comment: what about the 1000 and 2000?!

Comment: @user1570048  I have no idea what you are talking about.  2000? There are brilliant people here.  If you provide more information I'm sure you will have an answer in minutes.

Comment: i have like 36000 records for example i want to be able to select between 23500 and 24000 and so on :)

Comment: @user1570048 You have been asked a number of times about how the records are ordered. Just exactly how is record 23,500 determined? If you can provide that, I'm sure an answer would be forthcoming.

Comment: alphabetically by column called "name"

Answer (score 2):

In most databases, you would use something like `row_number() over (order by col1, col2)` to assign a row number to a specific ordering. Then you can request rows x through y. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Since MS-Access doesn't have analytic functions like `row_number()`, you have to be a bit more creative. [Here's a KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208946) that might help you.